# Outlier in the Alpha_Shapes_2 CGAL demo

Tags: cgal

I started using CGAL for a project, and I wanted to test alpha shapes with the alpha shapes 2 demo, furnished with CGAL. My input file has been correctly formatted (cf http://pastelink.me/dl/c83d1b warning 22087 lines), but I still have an outlier (cf http://bit.ly/YYZjtp). Is it due to a bug in the demo or too much points on the input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file format is not the correct one, it should be:

```
x1 y1
...
xn yn
```

Simplices in the Alpha-complex will be displayed in light blue.

Comment: Ok, it's odd since the examples in the data file have the number of points in the 1st line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the first line that indicates the number of points, because the "open()" function of the demo just read points until end-of-file. The file formats in CGAL are not consistent at all. I fell guilty: as a developer myself, I made my own file formats without trying to unify with others. We all did that. :-(